# When projecting data the distance between different coordinate locations overestimated or underestimated?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I was wondering as we project data is the distance between different coordinate locations always going to be underestimated on a flat map surface with respect to the distance between locations on the ellipsoid or overestimated? Also, could it be constant with the map surface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Metric_properties_of_maps),

> Many properties can be measured on the Earth's surface independent of
> its geography:
>
> - Area
> - Shape
> - Direction
> - Bearing
> - Distance
>
> Map projections can be constructed to preserve some of these properties at the expense of others.

As there are any number of possible projections, and some will preserve or distort distance at the expense of other properties, the answer to your question is "It depends".

It depends on the projection. If your projection distorts distance, then it's possible that the distance will possibly overestimated in some areas and underestimated in others. If it preserves distance, [Equidistant Projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection#Equidistant), then it may distort direction or area, etc.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much.